# Execute an exe file in different folders

Tags: matlab, exe

I have a programme (in exe format) used to create one image result. Usually, when I use it, I copy the executable in a folder of images, and I type the command on  msdos console. Now, i want to try to automatize that with different folders, each one with its images.

What I want to do is that matlab execute the programme in every folder. What I've been doing is the following:

```
Path= 'C:\Tools\'
a= dir (fullfile(Path,'*'))
fileNames = { a.name };

for k = 1:length(fileNames)
   system('C:\programme.exe')
end
```

It's not working properly. Can be because is not executing the programme in each folder?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to actually move your `programme.exe` into the folder first so maybe something like:

```
Path= 'C:\Tools\'
a= dir (fullfile(Path,'*'))
fileNames = { a.name };

for k = 1:length(fileNames)
   copy('C:\programme.exe', [fileNames, '\programme.exe'])
   system('programme.exe')
end
```

You might have some other problems though, for example you only want folder names when you call dir so you might want to ignore any name with a `.` in it:

```
Path= 'C:\Tools\'
a= dir (fullfile(Path,'*'))
Names = { a.name };
ind = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)(any(ismember(x,'.'))),b,'uni',0));
folders = Names(~ind)  

for k = 1:length(folders)
   copy('C:\programme.exe', [fileNames, '\programme.exe'])
   system('programme.exe')
end
```

But I think you'd probably rather use `move` than `copy` which I'll leave for you to do

Answer (score -1):

Looks like changing the working directory would do the trick:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html

```
cd(Path)
```